# Can't get MDI tab order right

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I'm using QtDesigner and have an MDI application with two tabs. I can't seem to get the tabs to open up the way I want them to. I'd like subwindow to have the focus and be the first one on the left when the application opens up. So 'subwindow_2' would be on the right and would not have the focus when the application opens.

I have the focus correct when the application opens. But the tab order is wrong. In other words the focus is on 'subwindow' but that shows up on the right instead of the left.

I've tried a number of things in QtDesigner such as changing activation order between creation order and  stacking order but that seems to have no effect. How do I fix this ?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from phreqMDI import Ui_MainWindow

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyForm,self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)       

        self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.ui.subwindow_2)
        self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.ui.subwindow)
```

Someone mentioned that pyuic4 doesn't do well with MDI. Perhaps there is something I need to change in my code instead of doing it in QtDesigner ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add them in the correct tab order, and then explicitly activate the relevant subwindow:

```
    self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.ui.subwindow)
    self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.ui.subwindow_2)
    self.ui.mdiArea.setActiveSubWindow(
        self.ui.mdiArea.subWindowList()[0])
```

**PS**:

For some reason, it seems necessary to use the [subWindowList](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmdiarea.html#subWindowList) when setting the active subwindow during `__init__`. Passing the return value of `addSubWindow` to `setActiveSubWindow` didn't work for me - but that may be a platform-specific thing (I tested on Linux).

**UPDATE**:

So, assuming you're on Windows, there do seem to be some platform-specific differences. As a workaround, try setting the active subwindow with a timer, like this:

```
    self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.ui.subwindow)
    self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.ui.subwindow_2)
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10,
        lambda: self.ui.mdiArea.setActiveSubWindow(
                self.ui.mdiArea.subWindowList()[0]))
```

Comment: I made the suggested change. The tabs are now in the right order but the focus is wrong. Upon opening, the focus is on subwindow_2 instead of subwindow.

I tried changing the index in the setActiveSubWindow statement from [0] to [1] to see if that helped. It didn't do anything at all. Setting it to [2] kicked out an error as expected.

Comment: @user3720101. I have added an alternative solution to my answer.

Comment: First, I want to thank you for all the help. I am learning a lot from these answers !

The correction you suggested works perfectly. It does exactly what I'm looking for.

Before closing this out, I wonder if I might ask why the single shot timer is needed. I think the statement says, wait 10 ms, then run the setActiveWindow method. Why is a 10 ms wait period needed ? Also, why is lamda needed ?

I also wonder why I can't get this done in QtDesigner. Does this all get back to PYUIC4 and MDI ?

Thanks in advance for your comments

Comment: @user3720101. It's because the code is being executed before the event-loop has started, and also before all the windows have been shown. The QTimer posts a single timer-event to the end of the event queue, allowing all the currently pending events to get processed before attempting to activate the window. The `lambda` is just a way of defining a signal handler in-line - it could be replaced with a dedicated method if needed. None of this has got anything to do with pyuic. The only issue there is that it does not generate boiler-plate code for adding the sub-windows.